# Is photoshop is allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, software, photos

I have noticed and personally related to the photoshop field that some people doing photo editing by using softwares. Some people edit the photos of respectful ladies for their ratings and business. But sometimes I realize that it is harmful for the respectful families or not. I want to ask that it is allow in Islam to crop and edit photos. If yes, then what are the limitations of doing photoshop according to Islamic Shareeáh? **Please give a reference of fatwa of Islamic scholars or reference of other authentic narrations.**

Comment: Yes, but not the premium edition! JK You people never  ceases to amaze me, at least explain why you think it may be Haram! Any thing can be used for Harmful purpouses, it dosent make it Haram, you can use forks to puncture peoples tyres, does that mean that forks are Haram or the act of damaging others property?

Comment: You are right brother..
But I want to know that what are the limitations according to Shareeah.
forks are also use for torturing people. Sometimes people become vulgar when using forks.

Comment: If anybody do not have proper answer or do not want to give answer then he/she do not have right to give negative vote on my question.
If anybody want to give negative vote on question then he/she should mention the valid reason.

Comment: Aboudi mentioned the valid reason; this is legalistic thinking without any indication of even a hunch that what you're asking about might be haram per se.

Comment: Yes, exactly.. I want complete answer with different fatwas of famous islamic scholors..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Photoshop is not haram but it matters that what are you doing on Photoshop if its allowed then its okay if its not allowed then its haram.

Lets see this in this way that you can keep a knife or a gun in your home for safety but you cannot use it for committing murder. Just like that you can use Photoshop but for positive use.

And there is no permission to edit the other girls photo to use there ratings and all its totally haram like i said using Photoshop is okay but what are you doing on Photoshop that can be halal or haram.

Sleeping is not haram but if you sleep with a blond girl that is haram. did you ask anybody that is Sleeping haram or not. you will surely ask that sleeping with a blond girl is haram or not.

Technology is halal it depends on your usage. ask questions for your usage that i am doing this is it halal or haram ask for you acts don't ask for technology.