# Is photoshoping halal?

Tags: fiqh, image, halal-haram, photos

I know photoshoping the pictures of animate beings is haram.but is it okay to Photoshop or edit the images of inanimate objects.Actually,I'm not telling about changing it's look I'm asking about the photo editing such as cropping,adjusting colour etc.Is it permissible? For example : turn a colorful photo of sky into black and white.I think it's called photoshoping.Is it permissible?

Comment: Is there any reason you think it would be haram?

Comment: I'm feeling like that...Idk,can you tell me?

Comment: @The Z can u tell me Idk if it's just waswasa or not...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is photoshop is allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/is-photoshop-is-allowed-in-islam)